# css - Animate background of transparent image

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create a bottom to top filling animation of a background color below an image with a transparent section, so, for example, I have the following image (assume grey is the transparent part):

[image]

and I would like to create an animation like this:

[image]

Essentially i'm trying to make the background of the image slide from bottom to top and I want for the fill amount to be dynamic (0-100% fill amount).
My HTML has a format similar to this:

```
<div>
  <img width="100" height="100" src="../img.png" />
</div>
```

I can adjust the image and html layout to support the animation if needed.

Edit: to clarify, I'm going to use an image, what i meant is that i can customise the image itself, but it might be a new image later on and i prefer to make it robust to the given image (relying only on the transparency part).

Comment: You should probably use SVG for this purpose which allows you to seamlessly animate the `path`s and `fill`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use gradient and animate background-size:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    /*replace the radial-gradient with your image*/
    radial-gradient(circle at center,transparent 50%,red 52%),
    /*this linear-gradient for the animation*/
    linear-gradient(green,green) bottom,
    /*bottom layer*/
    grey;
  background-size:auto,100% 0%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:2s;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:auto,100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: works perfectly, is it also possible to size the image replaced by the radial gradient to fit the container?

Comment: @Jellof yes, in the background size you will see two value, auto and `100% 0%` each value is for a gradient, so the first one (auto) is for the radial gradient and the image you will place there, so replace it with `cover` or `container` or any value you want

Comment: much obliged :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use image, you can use pure css. Also [fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/a29rv8bs/44/).

```css
.star {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%);
  background-color: grey;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
} 

.star .inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: fill-star 2s;
}

.fill-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
}


@keyframes fill-star {
  0%   { transform: translateY(100%) }
  100% { transform: translateY(0) }
}
```

```html
<div class="fill-container">
  <div class="star">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This totally works (for modern browsers). However, some older browsers may not have good support for [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: it's going to be an image (and the image might change in the future), the star was just an example but it could potentially be landscape with a missing mountain :)